# How many people does ISRO employ?

Tags: space-industry, isro

The Indian Space Research Organization (ISRO) is the space program of the Republic of India. How many people are employed by ISRO?

Comment: I've included my answer below according to my research, but a more fully fleshed answer addressing contractors, etc. is welcome.

Comment: While this question certainly is on-topic, it seems like it's purpose is to "seed" the site with questions.  Generally speaking, that's not a great idea since the Stack Exchange model is for people to organically ask questions they actually face.  We want experts in Space and Space Exploration to be excited about answering questions here.

Comment: @JonEricson That was not my intent. I was curious about the ISRO employee base and I couldn't find any information. I happened to find some while I was in the process of drafting my question, but it was incomplete so I thought I would post it so that others could help flesh it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this link](http://www.linkedin.com/company/isro) and [this pdf](http://www.isro.org/pdf/HumanResources.pdf), there are 14713 staff working under ISRO as of 2012.

Comment: I can't reach any of those links, can you check if there dead links.  It also possible is just a problem on my end. @Hash

Answer (score 2):

It would seem according to [this table](http://www.isro.org/pdf/rit10.pdf) on the ISRO site that they had 15,483 employees as of 2010.